# Typescript make a map that has array as key and array as value

Tags: typescript

I have 2 maps, 1 for class, another for subject.

```
const classMap = new Map<number,string>();
classMap.set(1,"class-1");
classMap.set(2,"class-2");
const subjectMap = new Map<number,string>();
subjectMap.set(102,"math");
subjectMap.set(202,"physics");
subjectMap.set(206,"bioogy");
```

I want another map to make it fixed which class should have which subject

so if I input 1,102  -> that means class -1 should have only math

to be clear inputting 1,102 will only show **math**

Should I use map? set? something else?

How can I do that ? Is there any easier way ?

[ I mean a binding,

like class 1 will only have math,

no other class should have math

math (code - 102) is only accessible if i put the class 1 code (1) after it

to achieve that

let say, x is a variable (it can be map / object / anything else)

so

```
x[1,101] // will give  us "math"  for array
```

or

```
x([1,101]) // will give us "math" for map or set
```

So I need help to build a variable like this (it, can be map or anything

]

Comment: I still don't quite understand your requirement. Maybe you could provide some Code with what you are expecting to happen with what inputs?

Comment: You might have to give a couple more examples of input; maybe something a little more interesting.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils is it clear now

Comment: @DavidLosert is it clear now

Comment: Hm, a bit more, however I am afraid that what you want here is not valid javascript syntax. But there might be another way depending on your requirement: You want a third map which joins classes with subjects, right?

Comment: @DavidLosert yes

Comment: If the relatiosn are unique anyways (as far as I understand), why don't you just build a single object structure rather than having three maps? E.g. `const classMap = { 1 : { name: 'class-1', subjects: { 102: 'math'}}}` - this way, you could access it like `classMap[1][102]`

Comment: @DavidLosert your example is perfect for my case, a lot of thanks, however, class and subject are coming from db, so what my 3rd map should look like? my first 2 maps look like  Map<number,string>

Comment: ok thanks. i will try that

Comment: Sorry, had to delete the type as it won't work with proper formatting in the comments.
I will prepare an answer for it.

Comment: @DavidLosert sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, you could do something like this:

```js
type ClassSubjectLink = {
    [classId: number]: {
        className: string
        subjects: {
            [subjectId: number]: string
        }
    }
}

const subjectLinks: ClassSubjectLink = {
  1: {
    name: 'class-1',
    subjects: {
      102: 'math'
    }
  }
}

console.log(subjectLinks[1].subjects[102]) // 'math'
```

You would'nt need another map here, but can go for a plain object structure.